# How to count diffrent rows in MySQL ? (three columns as a whole)

Tags: sql, mysql, count, rows

How to count rows with distinct values on any of the three columns: `col1`, `col2`, `col3`?

Comment: i think you need a little more description as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: This question makes no sense.  Please use complete sentences and explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: Not a real question as it stands...

Comment: are you saying you want to determine the number of rows in which those 3 columns are different? if so Quassnoi has the simplest and straight forward answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT col1, col2, col3)
FROM    mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Blind kick:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM YourTable
WHERE  Col1 <> Col2 OR Col1 <> Col3 OR Col2 <> Col3
```